# Simplify the following vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am a beginner in VBA programming. I have recorded the following vlookUp via the macro recorder. How can I shorten and simplify the code for this?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],oldStockAge!C[-7]:C[1],8,0)"
    Range("J5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],oldStockAge!C[-8]:C,9,0)"
    Range("D5:J5").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D5:J399")
    Range("D5:J399").Select
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.If you need more inforamtion, please come back to me.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how I can address the last cell (Selection.Autofill.Destination).

Comment: Can you edit your question and place a picture with the involved sheets/ranges, please?

Comment: Sorry, I wonted asking which is the **active cell** address...

Comment: Sorry, the active sheet name is "PIV KUnden SO & Stataus .  My request (vlookup) then goes through the data sheet "oldStockAge". The range in sheet "PIV KUnden SO & Stataus is D5:J399). The range should then be dynamic, as it can be enlarged or reduced.

Comment: Do you place the first formula in D5? Which is your first active cell (where placed the first formula) address? Are there formulas in the range D5:J5?

Comment: Yes, correct  the formulas are placed in th erange D5:J5.

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry... Which is the active cell address from the line: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],oldStockAge!C[-7]:C[1],8,0)"`? Then, do you want placing the formula in more than a cell? I suppose that in the range E5:I5 there are already other formulas. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, I have to place formula in more cells -> D5:J5 in sheet "PIV KUnden SO & Stataus because I have the same range in the "oldStockAge sheet whre I need the information / value from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next fast function able to place the `Vlookup` result for all involved range in an array and drop its content at once. I cannot understand what's happening before J5 cell (D5:I5)... The code returns the `VLookup` result in column J:J, starting from J5:

```
Sub OptimizedVlookup()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shOld As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngB As Range, rngBJ As Range, lastR2 As Long, arrVlk

   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set shOld = Worksheets("oldStockAge")
    lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastR2 = shOld.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rngB = sh.Range("B5:B" & lastR)
    Set rngBJ = shOld.Range("B2:J" & lastR2)
    
    arrVlk = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngB, rngBJ, 9, False)

    sh.Range("J5").Resize(UBound(arrVlk), 1).Value = arrVlk
End Sub
```

A different version:

```
Sub OptimizedVlookupMoreColsVersion2()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shOld As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngB As Range
 Dim rngBJ As Range, lastR2 As Long, arrVlk, iRow As Long, i As Long

   iRow = 5
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set shOld = Worksheets("oldStockAge")
    lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastR2 = shOld.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rngB = sh.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & lastR)
    Set rngBJ = shOld.Range("B2:J" & lastR2)
    For i = iRow To lastR
        arrVlk = Application.IfError(Evaluate("=VLOOKUP(B" & i & "," & rngBJ.Address(external:=True) & ",{3,4,5,6,7,8,9},FALSE)"), "N/A")
        If TypeName(arrVlk) = "String" Then
             sh.cells(i, "D").Resize(1, 7).Value = "N/A"
        Else
            sh.cells(i, "D").Resize(1, UBound(arrVlk)).Value = arrVlk
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

In order to **write the** `VLookup` formula, not its result, please try the next way:

```
Sub VlookupFormula()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shOld As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngB As Range, rngBJ As Range, lastR2 As Long

   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set shOld = Worksheets("oldStockAge")
    lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastR2 = shOld.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rngB = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR)
    Set rngBJ = shOld.Range("B2:J" & lastR2)

    sh.Range("J2:J" & lastR).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2," & rngBJ.Address(external:=True) & ",9,0)" 
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

If I correctly understood your need, the next code will place formulas able to return from all correspondent columns of the range "D:J":

```
Sub OptimizedVlookupMoreCols()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shOld As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngB As Range
 Dim rngBJ As Range, lastR2 As Long, arrVlk, iRow As Long, i As Long

   iRow = 5 'the row where from the data will be returned
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set shOld = Worksheets("oldStockAge")
    lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastR2 = shOld.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rngB = sh.Range("B" & iRow & ":B" & lastR)
    Set rngBJ = shOld.Range("B2:J" & lastR2)
    For i = 3 To 9
        arrVlk = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngB, rngBJ, i, False)
        sh.cells(iRow, i + 1).Resize(UBound(arrVlk), 1).Value = arrVlk
    Next i
End Sub
```

And the next one will write formulas to return the same data:

```
Sub VlookupFormulaMoreCols() 
 Dim sh As Worksheet, shOld As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngB As Range
 Dim rngBJ As Range, lastR2 As Long, arrVlk, i As Long, iRow As Long

   iRow = 5
   Set sh = ActiveSheet
   Set shOld = Worksheets("oldStockAge")
    lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastR2 = shOld.Range("B" & sh.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Set rngB = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR)
    Set rngBJ = shOld.Range("B2:J" & lastR2)
    'create the first range (row 5) Vlookup formulas:
    For i = 3 To 9
        sh.cells(iRow, i + 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2," & rngBJ.Address(external:=True) & "," & i & ",0)"
    Next i
    sh.Range("D" & iRow, "J" & iRow).AutoFill destination:=sh.Range("D" & iRow, "J" & lastR)
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it/them.

Comment: I have customized both codes. They both work very well. But now I only get the result in column D5. How can I adjust this for column E-D?

Comment: I am driving now..  I asked abour that part but you did not clarify it

Comment: I will try helping when I will be at home. But try beter clarify what formulas exist in all involved cells in range D5:G5...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, Thank you very much for your support.I'll try to explain it again.  The lookup value is in sheet "PIV Kunden SO & Stataus " in column B (starts from B5). The table_array is sheet "oldStockAge" B5:J till End of the used cells). Col-Index_number is 2-8 (column D-J). As mentioned above, I tried to adjust both of your codes, but they only work for one column - in this case column D.

Comment: @Gogi: So would you like to have in all the range (D5:J5) `VLookup` formulas able to return from the same table_array, in a way to return from D to J in each corresponding column?

Comment: Yes correct vlookup or array function. I would prefer array.

Comment: @Gogi: please, check the updated code. After **Edited** and send some feedback.

Comment: Both codes works. Thank you for your effort and patience.

Comment: @Gogi: Glad I could help! But we here, when somebody answer our answer, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the offered solution works. Our main goal is to make as many people as possible learning...

Comment: @Gogi: No, anybody asking a question can mark an answer as accepted one. You maybe did no understand where is that check box... Look above to the left side of my answer, below the arrows having a zero between them. When you will tick it, a green check will appear marking the answer. But, if you will not find it, this is not such a big deal. You can do it whenever you want or you don't do it at all. I do not have a problem with that. Have a nice evening!

Comment: HI FaneDuru, as alread mentioned  I have adjusted your code a bit, because another table has been added. Maybe you can check the code and give me some advice how to solve the issues. Thank you!

Comment: @Gogi: Please, delete all pseudo answers, as I already told you! It is not allowed to clarify anything placing an answer. An answer should be an answer! You risk to be excluded... I am driving again. Please edit your question and place there the clarification. Or  better, start another question, post one of my codes and ask for something else you need. This is the way here. Until I will be at home, maybe somebody else will clarify the issue.

Comment: Gogi: I can see that you deleted the question. Did you place it as a new one? If so and nobody answered it, if you tag me showing the link to reach it, I will try helping. I was not available the previous days in the evening.

Comment: Hi, yes I did as you suggested.  You can find it under "Convert formulas to values and remove special characters"